# HandlebarsJS registerHelper for comparing two dates

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to create a helper where I can compare two dates between each other, and depending if a certain date has passed to show specific HTMl elements or not. I have some data which I receive from a remote JSON which contains a "date" field. So for example:

```
data: {
   date: "2014-10-04",
   event: "some past event,
}, {
  date: "2014-12-06",
  event: "some future event,
...
```

So, If the date has passed , I want to either hide the HTML or archive it, and the upcoming events I want to display of course. So far I tried this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('has_passed', function(dateString, options) {
    var current_date = moment(dateString).format("YYYY-MM-DD").toUpperCase(); // The current date
    if(current_date> WHAT HERE???) {
       return options.fn(this);  // if current date is "bigger" than the passed date show html
    }
});
```

And my HTML looks simply like this for now

```
{{#has_passed date}}
    <div>
        <h1>blablabla</h1>
    </div>
{{/has_passed}}
```

Clearly, this doesnt work so can anyone help me out here??

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use query functions of **[momentjs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/)**

Then your helper would like so:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("has_passed", function(dateString, options) {
  if(moment(dateString).isAfter(moment())){
    return options.fn(this);
  } else {
    return options.inverse(this);
    }
});
```

see this [fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/wMmHS/71/)

Comment: don't know why it doesn't work. checked on different pc and it's fine. what do you see in *Result* area?

Comment: Should be isBefore